# How to include filename automatically in XCode code Snippet

Tags: xcode

I want to know is it possible including filename like `#file` in XCode snippet.

I can't find way to achieve this. Thank you

I tried

```
extension #file {
  <#body#>
}
```

It is possible as Variable in Jetbrains IDE or VSCode.